# Cross-compile to Beagleboard-XM using CMake and Clang

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, cross-compiling, beagleboard

I am trying to make a cross-compilation toolchain script for my BeagleBoard XM, but it doesn't work : the basic c++ includes (`<algorithm>`, etc...) aren't found when compiling.

Here is my toolchain file, made by following these two tutorials:

- http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html
- http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#The_toolchain_file

The file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX "")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  clang++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-target armv7a-unknown-eabi -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a8 --sysroot=/mnt/beagle/")

# where is the target environment
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /mnt/beagle /mnt/beagle/usr)
# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

`/mnt/beagle` is a SD Card with a copy of the system in my BeagleBoard, with all the necessary development packages, etc. installed.

Both the host and the guest are under Debian Jessie.

As a side question, I also have the android SDK & NDK installed. Is it possible to use them as a cross-compile environment, since it's ARMv7, or does the android NDK bring significant changes ?